# How to allow # ? & characters in URL while still allowing query strings

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site that allows users to create a page based on user input `example.com/My Page`

The problem is if they create a url like `example.com/H & E Photos` or `example.com/#1 Fan Club`

Once php decodes the url, it tries to parse those characters into a hash (or a query string in the case of `?`)

In my .htacess I am doing this `([^/]+?)`

What is the typical way of handling a situation like this? Ideally, without going to an id system (example.com/131234121). Poor planning on my part :(

EDIT. Talking about PHP here. url is encoded when it hits the server, php decodes before parse regex and url

Comment: @Herohtar Talking about php here. php decodes the url before it parses it.

Comment: Then why did you tag the question with JavaScript? In any case, you can't use those characters in a URL without encoding them.

Comment: @Herohtar Fixed. How do I encode them in php?

Comment: [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP to create/handle storing entries for user-entered-URLs then use htmlentities on the string before trying to handle it.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, what I was looking for was a rewrite flag.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags

`B  Escape non-alphanumeric characters before applying the transformation.`

This allows you to send percent-encoded strings to the URL without them being decoded beforehand.

So it was actually an apache thing and not PHP. Sorry for the misleading question.